# Variable size array GLSL

Tags: java, glsl, lwjgl

I am working on creating shaders for an OpenGL/Java engine that I am building.  I have searched for a while, but I cannot find a way to have an array of variable size.  I know that I can create a statically sized one like:

```
uniform vec3 variable[4];
```

But how would I go about creating an array of size X based on what I load to the shader from the CPU, if this is even possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GLSL does not allow varying array sizes. It does however, as of OpenGL 4, support Shader Storage Buffer Objects which can be varying sizes.

More information on SSBOs: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object

Thinking about it now, a hack way of doing it as well could be to encode your data into a texture and then pass that into the shader. For example, each of the 4 rgba components could be 1 byte of the data you wanted to pass. For data larger than a byte, you would break it out into bytes.

Answer (score 7):

You can't.

Either do as CConard96 said, or if you can't use SSBOs then just declare an hardcoded maximum value and set a lower value that you need.

For example like Nicol Bolas says [here](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182312-Uniform-Buffer-Objects-dynamic-sized-arrays-and-lights?p=1253008&viewfull=1#post1253008):

```
#define MAX_NUM_TOTAL_LIGHTS 100
struct Light {
  vec3 position;
  float padding;
}
layout (std140) uniform Lights {
  Light light[MAX_NUM_TOTAL_LIGHTS];
  int numLights;
}
```